# Viewmodel definition differences

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, viewmodel

What is/are the difference(s) between this:

```
define(["knockout"],
    function (ko) {
        return (function () {
            var self = this;
            self.Person = {
                firstName: ko.observable(),
                lastName: ko.observable(),
                Age: ko.observable()
            };
        });
    });
```

and

```
define(['knockout'], 
   function (ko) {
    return function appViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.Person = {
            firstName: ko.observable(),
            lastName: ko.observable(),
            Age: ko.observable()
        };
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing.  The latter a named function, but it's only accessible inside of the module callback scope so you couldn't use the name anyway.  I suppose it's to add clarity to the purpose of the function.